# type of 'USART0_RX_vect' defaults to 'int' [enabled by default]

Tags: c, warnings, compiler-warnings, avr

Learning AVR C programming i end up getting a warning from

```
int ISR(USART0_RX_vect) {
    // blah blah blah...
    return 0;
} 
//Warning   1   type of 'USART0_RX_vect' defaults to 'int' [enabled by default]
```

Why is this warning appearing and what actions are required to remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell your syntax is just wrong.  `ISR` is a macro that simplifies the definition of an interrupt handler routine. `ISR` resolves to an `__attribute__` decorated function which signature already specifies the return type `void`.

`USART0_RX_vect` will be resolved to something like `__vector_18` (ATMEGA128).

Something like this will be the define-substituted result:

```
void __vector_18 (void) __attribute__ ((signal,__INTR_ATTRS));
void __vector_18 (void) {
    // your code would appear here
}
```

So just omit the return type since is and has to be `void`.

Comment: I guess that in that case it should even not compile as of `int void` mixture in return type, but OP claimed that only warning message has appeared.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: True. Something from the OP doesn't add up.

Comment: Be my guest and test it.  It does compile...
I wish there was a Pascal compiler for this :)

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like at first place (unless in your case `ISR` is a macro that expands into some form) it is so called *old-style function definion* where type `int` is implicitely applied to such parameter as `USART0_RX_vect`. I would recommend to change it into prototype with explicite type:

```
int ISR(int USART0_RX_vect) {
    // blah blah blah...
    return 0;
}
```

Note that such old-style definition with implicit type is incorrect since C99. However if you want (for some obscure reason) to keep old-style, then here you go:

```
int ISR(USART0_RX_vect)
int USART0_RX_vect;
{
    // blah blah blah...
    return 0;
}
```

Such old-style definitions "survived" in modern C standard, because of portability with existing code base. As a good practice I would suggest to avoid them, in `gcc` compiler you can add `-Wold-style-definition` option to issue warning for them.

Note that identifiers with all-uppercase letters in C are conventionally recognized as macro definitions.